# Reading bytes in a file :java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException

Tags: java, exception, io, byte

I have gone through the similar posts but none of them really answered my question. Hence I post my question in a separate thread.
I need to skip some bytes in the file which I am reading in the byte array.I am trying to achieve this through code below

```
 1. byte [] readBytesToSKip = null;
 2. readBytesToSKip = new byte[(int)bytesToSkip];
 3. bytesReadToSkip = System.in.read(readBytesToSKip) ;
 4. if(bytesReadToSkip > 0)
 5. {
 6.      baos_.write(readBytesToSKip, 0, bytesReadToSkip);   
 7. }
```

But I get a `NegativeArraySizeException` at line 2 where the size exceeds `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. I am not sure how to achieve this otherwise.

`bytesToSkip` is long as I calculate in function below:

```
public static long bytesToLong1(byte[] bytes) {
        long value = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
        {
           value = (value << 8) + (bytes[i] & 0xff);
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `bytesToSkip`?  If it is a `long` and greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` you will not be able to skip it in one go. You'll have to do it in multiple steps.  As written, this question smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  Tell us what you're _actually_ trying to accomplish.

Comment: And what is the point of `bytesToSkip` being a `long` in the first place? as you can't read that much data at once? And what is the point of the code itself? Are you aware of `InputStream.skip()`?

Comment: @EJP I needed to read the bytes form standard input thats why I didnt use InputSream in first place.

Comment: Its a request to please at least explain before voting down the question.

Comment: You **are** using an `InputStream`. [`System.in`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in) is an `InputStream`.

Comment: @EJP I am not sure how would I use  `bytesRead = System.in.read(bytes) ;` with `InputStream` . Any example would be good

Comment: Sigh. You *are* using `bytesRead = System.in.read(bytes);` with `InputStream`. Are you reading what is written here? The point of my comment was that you should be calling `skip()` *instead* of all this code.

Comment: @EJP I see your point now.

Answer (score -1):

Starting from your posted `bytes->long` function

```
public static long bytesToLong1(byte[] bytes) {
    long value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
    {
       value = (value << 8) + (bytes[i] & 0xff);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Whenever `bytes.length==8` and the first byte is >= `128` in absolute value (in Java specific: it's a negative byte value), you'll end having a negative value for your long.

Example:

```
byte vals[]={0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF};

System.out.println(bytesToLong1(vals));
```

will result it `-1` being printed. Which will convert quite fine to an `int` with a `-1` value, but will still be improper for the length of an array.

Comment: 'If' is just as strong. There is no difference.

Comment: For 'some other values of "if" such as what? What imaginary language are you postulating here? This is Formal Logic 101.